# How To Get A Random Number To Count Down

Tags: random, count, numbers

I am trying to get a random number to count down to zero, but what i have keeps giving me a random number. Then every second it will generate a new random number between 4 and 11, and won't count down. if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance!
enter code here

```
            private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Random nuber = new Random();
        i = nuber.Next(4, 11);
        i--;

        textBox1.Text = i.ToString();

        if(i == 0)
        {
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();

            f2.Show();
            f1.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to lower the seed if you want a lower number, doesnt it seem obvious?

Comment: That's not what I was asking, though, doesn't it seem obvious?

Comment: When asking such a trivial question, don't be sarcastic towards the people trying to help you out. You need to show us more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, then you need to generate the number outside of the loop, in an initialization phase, in a static (global) variable. Then the timer tick will count it down. Note your f1 is created and then closed, it never shows, so is superfluous. Also you are creating a new form every time which is maybe not what you want.

Basically you need to move just the two statements:

```
random nuber = new Random();
i = number.next();
```

to wherever it is that you create the timer.

Comment: I'll give it a try. The game is on Form1 and then when the timer gets to zero it will open Form2, which is the main menu for the game I'm making.  But, Form1 doesn't close for some reason, Form2 opens and then Form1 just sits in the back. Is that what you meant by creating a new form?

Comment: I would need to see more code to understand what is going on, perhaps my form comments aren't relevant. But if you want the random number to count down, you need to assign it outside the loop, like when you create the timer, and store it somewhere where both the initialization code and the count down code can get to it. And please accept my answer, I need the points :)

Comment: Also the remark about the seed made little sense, since the seed will have nothing to do with the range of values the random number generator will actually generate.

Comment: for some reason it will not let me move the random generation out of the loop, it says "'WindowsFormApplication1.Form1.i' is a 'field' but used like a type'"

Comment: Sorry I bugged out on you, I needed sleep.

Comment: gotcha, the new edit you gave did indeed work for me

Comment: Good luck with your program. With experience these things will become clearer, event driven systems like this tend to make you scatter your logic in ways that are unobvious at first.